# Suma de tres fracciones con minimo comun multiplo

Tags: java

Hola me pueden ayudar a crear un metodo que ya obtenido el minimo comun multiplo de los tres denominadores haga la suma de las tres fracciones, este es mi metodo para sacar el minimo comun multiplo

```
public int MCM (int x, int y, int z){
     int nummax, i =1;
     nummax = x;
     if (y> nummax)
     nummax = y;
     if (z> nummax)
     nummax=z;
     i= nummax;
     while ((i % x!=0)||(i% y!=0)||(i%z!=0))
     i++;
     System.out.println("El MCM es ");
     return i;
}
```

Debe ser asi el metodo

```
public Racional Suma(Racional r1, Racional r2, Racional r3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debería hacer el método es  dividir en cada una de las fracciones los denominadores por el resultado del método MCM, guardar ese resultado en una variable aux y multiplicar el numerador por esa variable aux. Cuando tengas las tres fracciones las sumas y guardas el resultado en una nueva variable.

Puedes usar un for para los cálculos ya que por lo que veo tienes un numero fijo de términos.